# Moved CodeIgniter Script Doesn't work properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in re-installation of a Codeıgniter script.

in one of my website the script works but when I carry this script to my another domain it doesnt work.

```
Working URL : istoc.immobulus.com
Non-Working : modoko.modokoapp.com
```

So far there is no problem however when I type admin it doesnt work.

```
Working URL : istoc.immobulus.com/admin/
Non-Working : modoko.modokoapp.com/admin/
```

I've changed db and root URL accordingly 
Do you think that I missed to alter some other parts in the script ?
why this error can occur ?

PS. in logs I dont get any error

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Hooks Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Utf8 Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> URI Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Router Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> No URI present. Default controller set.

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Output Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Security Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Input Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Language Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Loader Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Config file loaded: application/config/site_config.php

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: language_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: string_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: url_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: text_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: zahmaci_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Helper loaded: file_helper

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Session Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Session routines successfully run

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Pagination Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Model Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2014-07-03 21:30:38 --> Controller Class Initialized
regards

Comment: Show us your routing file. How is /admin mapped and to what?

Comment: config/routes , but I think this is not the thing that I am looking for ?
`
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['hotel/(:any)'] = "hotel/index/$1";
$route['hotels/(:any)'] = "hotels/index/$1";

 `

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is either a `VirtualHost` or an `htaccess` problem. I say that because, from what I can glean, your index.php is working on the istoc server. It is also apparent that this URL works: http://modoko.modokoapp.com/index.php?/admin/login_form, while this URL doesn't: http://modoko.modokoapp.com/admin/login_form. This shows that the problem is clearly *not* a CodeIgniter issue but an Apache issue.

- Do you have RewriteEngine enabled for `modoko.modokoapp.com`?
- Is your RewriteRule properly formed?
- Do you have RewriteBase properly set?

Comment: I think rewrite is okay because,
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: when I type it I get : URL not found.

Comment: @zyrag As stated in the edit to the answer: this is *not* a CodeIgniter problem. Are you sure that Rewrite is enabled on that VirtualHost?

Comment: I will check it then will write the result. thank you

Comment: It is enabled do you think there may be another issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change database.php and config.php base_url when you try in new domain.
Also you need to enable mod_rewrite and change in .htaccess file in root directory.

ping me if its not clrear.

Comment: what is in your .htaccess file??

Comment: because of something small in htaccess file now it works :) thanks a lot everyone